# FirebaseError: Timestamp out of range

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to filter some items from a collection by date. Prior to doing the call, I am converting a date object to firebase's Timestamp, which should be doable according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp).

However, when I do try to do so, regardless of the date I pass in, I get the following error:

> FirebaseError: Timestamp seconds out of range: Tue Sep 03 2019 17:25:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Here is an example code of how this happens:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/functions'
import 'firebase/storage'

const now = new Date()
console.log(firebase.firestore.Timestamp(now))
```

I have included my imports in case this somehow matters.

Anyway, did I miss something? Is there something wrong?

Comment: `now` needs to be formated into the [iso 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: use [date.js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(now);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're linking to Android docs, but writing in JavaScript.  They aren't the same.

Use the static method `fromDate()` instead, which works for me using 6.5.0:

```
console.log(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()))
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Comment: Woops! That was the wrong link. Silly me! Anyway, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: I received this error in Javascript because some timestamp fields in Firestore have dates earlier than 1970-01-01.